# My Mulesoft flows are being executed more than once

Tags: foreach, data-migration, dataweave, mulesoft

I'm developing a data migration application between two databases, using Mulesoft's Anypoint Platform.

I keep getting duplicate key errors, and while debugging I realized my flows are being executed more than once.

Here's a part of the code:

```
<flow name="docLogicFlow" doc:id="7e901506-e31d-4d1a-baf0-e54fef27f083" >
    <flow-ref doc:name="DGD_TCONTENT Migration Flow Reference" doc:id="9139e02d-36b2-4c4c-a8bb-12fa1e372134" name="DGD_TCONTENTMigrationFlow" />
    <flow-ref doc:name="DOC_TFILECONTENTTYPE Migration Flow Reference" doc:id="ef67a89a-ecd9-416b-9bc4-4a67a91efd67" name="DOC_TFILECONTENTTYPEMigrationFlow" />
    <flow-ref doc:name="DOC_TFILESTORAGE Migration Flow Reference" doc:id="2adbb928-9f7e-44be-8a50-33bdceacfc2f" name="DOC_TFILESTORAGEMigrationFlow" />
</flow>
<flow name="docCleanFlow" doc:id="8278a9e1-64c7-4abc-8647-ce22c28f66c5" >
    <db:delete doc:name="Delete" doc:id="bc7920fa-ed99-4fe1-9337-a061f5ec800b" config-ref="Database_Config">
        <db:sql >DELETE FROM DGD_TCONTENT;
                 DELETE FROM DOC_TFILE;
                 DELETE FROM DOC_TFILECONTENTTYPE;
                 DELETE FROM DOC_TFILESTORAGE;</db:sql>
    </db:delete>
</flow>
<flow name="DGD_TCONTENTMigrationFlow" doc:id="cbdcdcb7-a22c-4636-ba02-639f12882700" >
    <db:select doc:name="Select DGD_TCONTENT from Oracle DB" doc:id="3b60f901-03f5-4213-8373-92b29abe6a3d" config-ref="MYCAREER_DEV_DB" >
        <db:sql >SELECT * FROM DGD_TCONTENT</db:sql>
    </db:select>
    <batch:job jobName="DGD_TCONTENTMigrationBatchJob" doc:id="3317b3d8-582c-4f6c-82be-2d84ccdbd28f" >
        <batch:process-records >
            <batch:step name="DGD_TCONTENTMigrationBatchStep" doc:id="a4d82fbe-96c7-4ff8-8fc9-5614f2963e60" >
                <batch:aggregator doc:name="DGD_TCONTENT Batch Aggregator" doc:id="64d3b1a3-bf3e-44c5-80f9-cf3f6a063cdf" size="20" >
                    <foreach doc:name="For Each" doc:id="1bea88df-b68a-4af9-9f7d-a0dbdf65d720" >
                        <db:stored-procedure doc:name="Insert into DGD_TCONTENT" doc:id="e942f30b-7f3c-4a1b-b175-2ad969ab39b9" config-ref="Database_Config">
                            <db:sql >{call InsertIntoContent (:CONTENT_ID, :CONTENT_TYPE, :CONTENT_EXT_ID, :CONTENT_TITLE, :CONTENT_SUMMARY, :CONTENT_URL, :CONTENT_FORMAT,
:CONTENT_OBSOLETE, :CONTENT_IMAGE_URL, :CONTENT_LANGUAGE, :CONTENT_DURATION, :CONTENT_DURATION_TYPE, :CONTENT_PROVIDER,
:CONTENT_INTERNAL, :CONTENT_CREATED_DATE, :CONTENT_MODIFIED_DATE)}</db:sql>
                            <db:input-parameters ><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
    CONTENT_ID              : payload.content_id,
    CONTENT_TYPE            : payload.content_type,
    CONTENT_EXT_ID          : payload.content_ext_id,
    CONTENT_TITLE           : payload.content_title,
    CONTENT_SUMMARY         : payload.content_summary,
    CONTENT_URL             : payload.content_url,
    CONTENT_FORMAT          : payload.content_format,
    CONTENT_OBSOLETE        : payload.content_obsolete,
    CONTENT_IMAGE_URL       : payload.content_image_url,
    CONTENT_LANGUAGE        : payload.content_language,
    CONTENT_DURATION        : payload.content_duration,
    CONTENT_DURATION_TYPE   : payload.content_duration_type,
    CONTENT_PROVIDER        : payload.content_provider,
    CONTENT_INTERNAL        : payload.content_internal,
    CONTENT_CREATED_DATE    : payload.content_created_date,
    CONTENT_MODIFIED_DATE   : payload.content_modified_date,
}]]]></db:input-parameters>

                        </db:stored-procedure>
                    </foreach>
                </batch:aggregator>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:process-records>
        <batch:on-complete >
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="42ae6570-e00d-4f0f-a2fa-3cd36ccc5a98" message="DGD_TCONTENT finished data migration."/>
        </batch:on-complete>
    </batch:job>
</flow>
<flow name="DOC_TFILEMigrationFlow" doc:id="40bf34a9-6b57-4640-9ebe-801f86da6331" >
    <db:select doc:name="Select DOC_TFILE from Oracle DB" doc:id="c29cd80b-272f-4d92-97b6-9c1c8a214fb9" config-ref="MYCAREER_DEV_DB" >
        <db:sql >SELECT * FROM DOC_TFILE</db:sql>
    </db:select>
    <batch:job jobName="MigrateDOC_TFILEBatchJob" doc:id="6cfb7fa7-eab5-4591-b188-10bd88f40efc" >
        <batch:process-records >
            <batch:step name="MigrateDOC_TFILEBatchStep" doc:id="82ab6f35-8867-46a7-9591-eb6f79ec64b4" >
                <batch:aggregator doc:name="DOC_TFILE Batch Aggregator" doc:id="8c9277d0-65aa-4bba-9c28-3acf272f2936" size="20" >
                    <foreach doc:name="For Each" doc:id="9f50fb18-16b9-4be5-bf98-b7b024546ee8" >
                        <db:stored-procedure doc:name="Insert into DOC_TFILE" doc:id="6a7b3f09-284d-4bc5-91ea-945d02195395" config-ref="Database_Config">
                            <db:sql >{call InsertIntoFile (:FILE_CODE,:FILECONTENTTYPE_CODE,:FILE_NAME,:FILE_SIZE,  :FILE_STATUS,:USER_CODE,    :FILE_DATA,:FILE_STORAGE_VALUE,:FILE_UPLOAD_CODE,
                            :FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP,:FILESTORAGE_CODE,:FILE_DATE_INSERT,:FILE_DATE_UPDATE,:FILE_DATE_DELETE)}</db:sql>
                            <db:input-parameters ><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
    FILE_CODE               : payload.file_code,
    FILECONTENTTYPE_CODE            : payload.filecontenttype_code,
    FILE_NAME           : payload.file_name,
    FILE_SIZE           : payload.file_size,
    FILE_STATUS         : payload.file_status,
    USER_CODE               : payload.user_code,
    FILE_DATA           : payload.file_data,
    FILE_STORAGE_VALUE      : payload.file_storage_value,
    FILE_UPLOAD_CODE        : payload.file_upload_code,
    FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP        : payload.file_upload_temp,
    FILESTORAGE_CODE        : payload.filestorage_code,
    FILE_DATE_INSERT        : payload.file_date_insert,
    FILE_DATE_UPDATE        : payload.file_date_upload,
    CONTENT_CREATED_DATE    : payload.content_created_date,
    FILE_DATE_DELETE    : payload.file_date_delete
}]]]></db:input-parameters>

                        </db:stored-procedure>
                    </foreach>
                </batch:aggregator>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:process-records>
        <batch:on-complete >
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="c51d684a-f195-4758-84b8-355fc8cda3b5" message="DOC_TFILE finished data migration."/>
        </batch:on-complete>
    </batch:job>
</flow>
<flow name="DOC_TFILECONTENTTYPEMigrationFlow" doc:id="4447f39a-aabf-48df-ae81-9c23a9c17927" >
    <db:select doc:name="Select DOC_TFILECONTENTTYPE from Oracle DB" doc:id="54a25f9f-d84f-4621-bc5b-b2578dcf4891" config-ref="MYCAREER_DEV_DB" >
        <db:sql >SELECT * FROM DOC_TFILECONTENTTYPE</db:sql>
    </db:select>
    <batch:job jobName="MigrateDOC_TFILECONTENTTYPEBatchJob" doc:id="f895d255-e3f4-4139-8c9c-bdba1f292abf" >
        <batch:process-records >
            <batch:step name="MigrateDOC_TFILECONTENTTYPEBatchStep" doc:id="3ff4c3ff-659d-4efc-ad81-e3e3f42d0afb" >
                <batch:aggregator doc:name="DOC_TFILECONTENTTYPE Batch Aggregator" doc:id="d7e56e72-172a-4322-acdd-a66a7e626224" size="20" >
                    <foreach doc:name="For Each" doc:id="d0e3b9ee-c820-4722-94cf-52ffabd14b04" >
                        <db:stored-procedure doc:name="Insert into DOC_TFILECONTENTTYPE" doc:id="0d873708-4611-42af-98c0-22f656bc5ec4" config-ref="Database_Config">
                            <db:sql >{call InsertIntoFileContentType (:CONTENTTYPE_CODE,:CONTENTTYPE_ID,:CONTENTTYPE_STATUS,:CONTENTTYPE_ICON,:CONTENTTYPE_NAME,
                        :CONTENTTYPE_DESCRIPTION)}</db:sql>
                            <db:input-parameters ><![CDATA[#[{
CONTENTTYPE_CODE            : payload.contenttype_code, 
CONTENTTYPE_ID              : payload.contenttype_id,
CONTENTTYPE_STATUS          : payload.contenttype_status,
CONTENTTYPE_ICON            : payload.contenttype_icon,
CONTENTTYPE_NAME            : payload.contenttype_name,
CONTENTTYPE_DESCRIPTION     : payload.contenttype_description,
 }]]]></db:input-parameters>
                        </db:stored-procedure>
                    </foreach>
                </batch:aggregator>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:process-records>
        <batch:on-complete >
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="fd4797d9-bca0-4b97-bca4-b95dce09c2bb" message="DOC_TFILE_CONTENTTYPE finished data migration."/>
        </batch:on-complete>
    </batch:job>
</flow>
```

BusinessLogicFlow that calls DocLogicFlow:

```
<flow name="mainFlow" doc:id="7c0a5bef-b3d5-442f-bff3-10d038f69a5e">
    <flow-ref doc:name="businesslogicFlow" doc:id="91360ede-4d71-44c7-9b64-8ee762e04ea0" name="businesslogicFlow" />
    <error-handler>
        <on-error-propagate enableNotifications="true" logException="true" doc:name="On Error Propagate" doc:id="488b507d-e26c-4c56-8759-8bb4f6645d71" type="ANY">
            <flow-ref doc:name="errorHandlingFlow" doc:id="afdaf73c-0137-4d60-84f6-5c41234771a3" name="errorHandlingFlow" />
        </on-error-propagate>
    </error-handler>
</flow>
<flow name="businesslogicFlow" doc:id="5aa7011d-8abd-453d-9459-c7322838f14a" tracking:enable-default-events="true">
    <db:select doc:name="Select" doc:id="58bc689c-b708-4b1b-b645-693735104a25" config-ref="MYCAREER_DEV_DB">
        <db:sql >select 1 from dual</db:sql>
    </db:select>
    <batch:job jobName="template-db2db-account-migrationBatch_Job" doc:id="af55c5cf-807b-4582-9868-66f144b0a8e9">
        <batch:process-records>
            <batch:step name="Batch_Step" doc:id="428bb0a0-5082-451d-9253-2b6f0a147719" >
                <flow-ref doc:name="Flow Reference" doc:id="ebf025cf-70b1-4145-8fd9-270d92c06420" name="docCleanFlow"/>
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="92c2d1da-fb59-4cb3-b1e6-ac5e9ae28922" message="DELETE COMPLETED"/>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:process-records>
        <batch:on-complete >
            <flow-ref doc:name="Flow Reference" doc:id="9a331b54-55e4-4818-9050-cf70cc348581" name="docLogicFlow"/>
        </batch:on-complete>
</batch:job>
```

Endpoint that calls businessLogicFlow:

```
<flow name="triggerFlow" doc:id="25a15396-5def-4f1c-bac2-6c7a769f4278" >
    <http:listener doc:name="/migrate" doc:id="ca1efe4f-1e53-428a-b439-c1d905246a34" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/migrate"/>
    <flow-ref doc:name="mainFlow" doc:id="9c665dd4-7df3-4e0d-a1eb-01ac63781ce7" name="mainFlow"/>
    <ee:transform doc:name="Build response" doc:id="2abddd58-c707-435a-a004-ec5ba9107429">
        <ee:message>
            <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
```

output application/json

---

{
    Message: "Batch Process initiated",
    ID: payload.id,
    RecordCount: payload.recordCount,
    StartExecutionOn: payload.creationTime as DateTime
 }
 ]]>

Does anybody know why this is happening? And how to avoid it?

Thank you!

Comment: The flows that you show are not a complete picture. There must be at least some other flow that triggers docLogicFlow. What is the flow that starts all this process, and what is the message source that triggers the start?

Comment: I'll add the other flows on the post, but it's only being called once.
Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

It looks that provided code is not the source of the duplication.
It could be something which is calling **docLogicFlow**

What flow calls it? Is it generated by some scheduler? Double check it - it may run flow again even previous flow is still working. Scheduler is indepnedent of flow exceution. It depends only on schedule. In general it could be many flows running in parallel from the same scehduler.

If it is not scheduler - check events what start this flow. My guess - these events come too often and your regular flow is still working. Look about Schedulers and Multiple Schedulers here https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/Multipleschedules.html

This is good you are using database. You can use its transction mechanism to prevent duplicstion. Always be ready that something can call flow again and again and reject duplicated requests. It's easy to in the DB environment. Just establish any lock and reject/ignore duplicated requests.

P.S. Your third flow refernce is not linked to anything. This one

```
<flow-ref doc:name="DOC_TFILESTORAGE Migration Flow Reference" doc:id="0bda80b0-e330-4e86-b0f1-acfeb57e031a" name="DOC_TFILESTORAGEMigrationFlow" />
```

Comment: It's being called by another flow, which is being called by a third flow and that one is being started by an HTTP Listener. I've checked the code but it's only being called once.
Thank you for the suggestion I'll try to implement that!